# How to schedule Azure worker role with rabbitmq Message Queue

Tags: c#, azure, rabbitmq, cloud

We are having RabbitMQ server which we use it for reading data from Database and push it to RabbitMQ Queue. This logic I wrote in worker role. I am not sure how to schedule this worker role using Windows Azure Scheduler. I have seen tutorials on Azure Scheduler which are using Service bus or some end points. But in my case I am using RabbitMQ. So I am new to azure . Somebody please help me in the right direction to schedule the Worker role with RabbitMQ

Any links related to Azure scheduler with RabbitMQ would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to schedule? Scaling? Reboots? Shutdowns?

Comment: We have data in text files.we dump the data into database using ssis and then we read the data and push it the queue for further processing.we wrote push logic in worker role. I hope this comes under scaling.we want to schedule this job. I hope I have given needed information if not please let me know